# JUnit 5 - new annotations - debug with JDB

Tags: java, junit, jdb

I'm having trouble debugging test methods (written in Java) that use [JUnit 5](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/) via [JDB](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdb/jdb_quick_guide.htm). More specifically, I can debug test methods with the annotation ['@Test'](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests), but I can't with methods that use the annotations ['@ParameterizedTest'](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests) and ['@RepeatedTest'](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-repeated-tests). When I try to debug with methods that use these annotations, JDB just doesn't stop during its execution, even adding breakpoints. I'll show an example to make it clearer:

## Example with @Test annotation - works as expected

#### Code

TestClass.java (example class)

```
public class TestClass 
{
    public long factorial(int x) 
    {
        long response = 1;

        for (int i=1; i<=x; i++) {
            response *= i;
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

TestAnnotation.java (test method)

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;


public class TestAnnotation 
{
    @Test
    public void test1()
    {
        TestClass tc = new TestClass();
        assertEquals(24, tc.factorial(4));   // Line 12
    }
}
```

#### Input (cmd)

```
jdb -sourcepath ./ -classpath lib/junit-jupiter-api-5.6.2.jar;lib/junit-jupiter-params-5.6.2.jar;lib/apiguardian-api-1.1.0.jar;lib/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.2;./ org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher -cp lib -c TestAnnotation --disable-banner --details=none

> stop at TestAnnotation:12
> run
```

#### Output

```
run org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher -cp lib -c TestAnnotation --disable-banner --details=none
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
>
VM Started: Set deferred breakpoint TestAnnotation:12

Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", TestAnnotation.test1(), line=12 bci=8
12              assertEquals(24, tc.factorial(4));

main[1] step into
>
Step completed: "thread=main", TestClass.factorial(), line=5 bci=0
5               long response = 1;

main[1]
...
```

## Example with @ParameterizedTest annotation - does not work as expected

#### Code

ParameterizedTestAnnotation (test method)

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ValueSource;


public class ParameterizedTestAnnotation 
{
    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(ints = {-1,0,1})
    public void test1(int num)
    {
        TestClass tc = new TestClass();
        assertEquals(1, tc.factorial(num));   // Line 14
    }
}
```

#### Input (cmd)

```
jdb -sourcepath ./ -classpath lib/junit-jupiter-api-5.6.2.jar;lib/junit-jupiter-params-5.6.2.jar;lib/apiguardian-api-1.1.0.jar;lib/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.2;./ org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher -cp lib -c ParameterizedTestAnnotation --disable-banner --details=none

> stop at ParameterizedTestAnnotation:14
> run
```

#### Output

```
run org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher -cp lib -c ParameterizedTestAnnotation --disable-banner --details=none
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
>
VM Started: Set deferred breakpoint ParameterizedTestAnnotation:14

The application exited
```

---

I am working on an application that needs to debug these methods through a shell (in this example, cmd), so it is necessary that debugging be done via command line, and not through an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), for example.

**Note:** The files I used in this example, along with the libraries used can be found [here](https://ufrgscpd-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/william_niemiec_ufrgs_br/EZfMfu_imAtCqOQxRtg5W9UBdrdnUbaKB81ms4omGlKFdg?e=Iygsxn).